ERROR: Failed to monitor for Free Swap Space
I have created a slave node on jenkins using username/password also ssh key-pair, when I the slave node opening ssh connection, the error "ERROR: Failed to monitor for Free Swap Space" is coming with the stack trace
This is a Unix agent
Agent successfully connected and online
ERROR: Failed to monitor for Free Swap Space
Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to Devops
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1787)
        at hudson.remoting.UserRequest$ExceptionResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:356)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1037)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1033)
        at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:66)
        at hudson.node_monitors.AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.monitorDetailed(AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:112)
        at hudson.node_monitors.AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.monitor(AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:76)
        at hudson.node_monitors.AbstractNodeMonitorDescriptor$Record.run(AbstractNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:324)
java.io.IOException: No suitable implementation found: os.name=NONSTOP_KERNEL os.arch=amd64 sun.arch.data.model=64
    at org.jvnet.hudson.MemoryMonitor.obtain(MemoryMonitor.java:93)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.MemoryMonitor.get(MemoryMonitor.java:59)
    at hudson.node_monitors.SwapSpaceMonitor$MonitorTask.call(SwapSpaceMonitor.java:129)
    at hudson.node_monitors.SwapSpaceMonitor$MonitorTask.call(SwapSpaceMonitor.java:124)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:377)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService.lambda$wrap$0(InterceptingExecutorService.java:78)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
Caused: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1039)
    at hudson.remoting.Channel$2.adapt(Channel.java:1033)
    at hudson.remoting.FutureAdapter.get(FutureAdapter.java:66)
    at hudson.node_monitors.AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.monitorDetailed(AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:112)
    at hudson.node_monitors.AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.monitor(AbstractAsyncNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:76)
    at hudson.node_monitors.AbstractNodeMonitorDescriptor$Record.run(AbstractNodeMonitorDescriptor.java:324)
[05/10/24 16:55:47] [SSH] SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed.

First of all is it common to see the "free swap space error" and secondly is it actually connecting because at the end it says "[SSH] SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed."

Can you share you jenkins version and java version? Can you also share your Node Monitoring Settings?

Yes, the node is connected successfully. Node monitoring doesn’t work because your node is running an os version that Jenkins doesn’t know how to monitor. It’s obviously not ideal, but shouldn’t cause any issues.
